# nginx configuration for uri having percent caracter

Tags: nginx

i'm searching for hours the right to to configure my nginx.

problem:
i'm having url like this: https://exemple.com/myAction/%123456
please note the %123456
unfortunatly this part is as it and can not be modified 
(i can't skip the %)

Nginx (tries to) interpret the %XX and sends modified URI to my controller:

- %403456 becomes @3456,
- %5B3465 becomes [3456 and so on

question:
is there a way to say to nginx to not change the %XX ?

thanks in advance

Comment: The `%` is a reserved character. To write a URI containing a literal `%`, it needs to be percent-encoded as `%25`. See this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_the_percent_character) for details.

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks, so in your opinion there's no way to use a rewrite rule something like **rewrite (/myAction/%)(.*)$ /myAction/%25$2;** ??\\i'm bad at nginx and rewriting but maybe it's possible

Answer (score 0):

In the part where you send it to your controller, use the variable `$request_uri`, its a non normalized uri with query string, use `$request_uri?` to drop the query strings.

```
$scheme://$host$request_uri?
or
$scheme://$host$request_uri
```